# how to add a space behind a specific character except when the character is at the beginning/end of the line

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a regex that changes all of these patterns:

```
anything1 * anything2* anything3
anything1* anything2 * anything3
anything1 * anything2 * anything3
anything1*anything2 *anything3
anything1 * anything2 *anything3
anything1*anything2*anything3
```

To this pattern:

```
anything1 *anything2* anything3
```

Here is my regex:

```
.replace(/\s*(\*+)\s*(.*?)\s*(\*+)\s*/g,' $1$2$3 ')
                                         ^      ^
                                           space
```

## [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iJ5hQ3/1)

---

Now I want if asterisk is in the beginning of the line, then first space removes. Like this:

```
*anything1* anything2 anything3
```

As you see, there isn't any space behind the first star *(Leftmost)*

Also if the string ends up with a asterisk then last space removes. Like this:

```
anything1 anything2 *anything3*
//                             ^ there isn't any space there
```

How can I do that?

---

**Note:** Maybe there is `**` instead of `*`. Something like this: `anything **anything** anything`

---

Summary: I'm trying to remove this space:

[image]

```
//                                              ^ this
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are OK with two separate regular expressions (which is far easier to read IMO):

```
.replace(/^\s+\*/g, '*')
.replace(/\*\s+$/g, '*')
```

Comment: 1. Can I use them as chain? 2. These two regex are the same with my regex and remove beginning and last spaces?

Comment: you can: `.replace(//, '').replace(//, '').replace(//, '')`

Comment: Ok, please lemme check it

Comment: Yes it works +1. Now I have three `replace()` just for doing a tiny thing. Is that optimized? To be honest, I am afraid this will reduce performance

Comment: Perhaps, but at the cost of easier to understand which some argue is more important. However, I combined it into one Regex. Check updated answer.

Comment: Ok ... And your alternative regex doesn't work, I doesn't handle spaces as well.

Comment: I need to this: `anything1{space}*anything2*{space}anything3`

Comment: My mistake. I've looked into it, and it can't be done. Problem is that you *need* to add spaces in the second argument (`' $1$2$3 '`), but you can't insert any regex expressions here. The chained `replace` is your best bet. The performance difference will be negligible at best.